# Как сделать красивый скриншот сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-дизайн, webbrowser, screenshots, graphics

Нужно сделать красивый макет-превью для сайта в стиле **OS X Yosemite**. Похожие сервисы: getcover, browsercover.me. Подскажите какие-либо сервисы, которые так умееют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервис не знаю. Если владеете фотошопом, может, вам поможет [скриншот FF33.1/Yosemite](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1e1nx00yl9cg9w/Screenshot%202014-11-20%2011.19.59.png?dl=0) и [Safari](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1b757rtiv09dmg8/Screenshot%202014-11-20%2011.24.34.png?dl=0).

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Найти бы сервис...